# Histogram equalization for python

Tags: python, image-processing, histogram, histogram-equalization

I have this routine to do histogram equalization of a photo:

```
def histeq(im,nbr_bins=256):

   #get image histogram
   imhist,bins = histogram(im.flatten(),nbr_bins,normed=True)
   cdf = imhist.cumsum() #cumulative distribution function
   cdf = 255 * cdf / cdf[-1] #normalize

   #use linear interpolation of cdf to find new pixel values
   im2 = interp(im.flatten(),bins[:-1],cdf)

   return im2.reshape(im.shape), cdf

#im = array(Image.open('AquaTermi_lowcontrast.jpg').convert('L'))
im = array(Image.open('Unequalized.jpg').convert('L'))
#Image.open('plant4.jpg').convert('L').save('inverted.jpg')

im2,cdf = histeq(im)

plt.imshow(im2)
plt.savefig("outputhisto.jpg")
```

When I run this with the [picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unequalized_Hawkes_Bay_NZ.jpg) from the wiki page for [histogram equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) it results in this:
[image]

Instead of properly adjusting the contrast of image to something along the lines of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Equalized_Hawkes_Bay_NZ.jpg). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dunno. Doesn't really matter when there's six upvotes though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you're just not rendering with the wrong colormap?  Try

```
plt.imshow(im2, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

Or

```
plt.imshow(im2, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
```

Comment: Genius! haha that was easy. And the exact syntax is `cmap=plt.cm.gray` not grey. Thanks!